# How to sort result by field?

Tags: pymongo

I have a simple example:

```
result = db.command({
    'findandmodify' : 'Task',
    'remove' : True
 })
print result
```

How to get first inserted element ? ( order by _id )

Answer (score 1):

The find_one method in pymongo should return the first document in the collection: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one